# Using ternary operator in lambda where condition

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, conditional-operator

This is how I retrieve my data using linq lambda expression.

```
var data = await _repo.GetAll().where(x => x.isDeleted = false).CountAsync();
```

And I also want to filter my data with _date.

```
bool filterWithDate = false;  
var _date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
```

`filterWithDate` will be pass by method parameter and it's dynamic.
If it's `true` , I want to filter by _date , if `false` , I will get all data.
I can check with `if(filterWithDate)` here , but I just want to filter in linq `where` condition with ternary operator to simplify my code.

```
var data = await _repo.GetAll().  
where(x => x.isDeleted = false 
&& (filterWithDate) ? x.date >= _date : ??? ).CountAsync();
```

Comment: return true as filtering is not required. Something like this  (filterWithDate) ? x.date >= _date : true

Comment: What if you have two of these lines? you can control which one should be filtered

Comment: @Bosco , using tinary in `where` would be more simplify.

Comment: @neeleshbodgal , `(filterWithDate) ? x.date >= _date : true` will ignore `x.isDeleted = false` too.

Comment: No it won't since it is an and condition

Comment: The term is [ternary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), not tinary.  =)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment,

You could use two lines instead and still use ternary operator

```
var data = filterWithDate ? 
               await _repo.GetAll().Where(x => x.isDeleted = false && x.date >= _date).CountAsync() : 
               await _repo.GetAll().Where(x => x.isDeleted = false).CountAsync();
```

Or You go full if statement

```
if(filterWithDate)
    await _repo.GetAll().Where(x => x.isDeleted = false && x.date >= _date).CountAsync();
else
    await _repo.GetAll().Where(x => x.isDeleted = false).CountAsync();
```

> This will save you a lot of thinking

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the comments on the question and also the answer from @Bosco, If you still would like to go with a sinlge-line change, you can try this...

```
var data = await _repo.GetAll().  
    Where(x => !x.isDeleted && (!filterWithDate || x.date >= _date)).CountAsync();
```